# Sentry for micro frontends

Tags: reactjs, sentry

Is there any possibility to initialise Sentry twice on a page? Use case would be error tracking for parts of the app that are inserted as microfrontend.

So errors happen in this part of the app should be send to the teams own sentry project. I also wonder if there is any way filter the errors so only the ones that are relevant for the microfrontend are send and others are filtered out. Could we use reacts error boundaries for that?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a way to initialize something called `Hub` with a second `dsn` like this:

```js
import {BrowserClient, Hub} from '@sentry/browser';

const client = new BrowserClient({
dsn: 'micorFrontEndSntryInstance'
});
const hub = new Hub(client)
```

this hub can passed to an `ErrorBoundary` wrapping your component.
In every `componentDidCatch` we can then send the error to the micro frontends sentry:

```js
componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    this.props.hub.run(currentHub => {
      currentHub.withScope((scope) => {
          scope.setExtras(errorInfo);
          currentHub.captureException(error);
      });
    })
  }
```

All the code is from [this example implementation](https://github.com/RobinCsl/sentry-in-react-micro-fe).

Comment: Actually, this solution works for component rendering but do not redirect event errors to the right hub :-(